# how to use input of form element by id as variable in jquery?

Tags: jquery

```
        <form id="search" method="GET" action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/bankdetailapi/?q=">
            <!-- {% csrf_token %} -->
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="q" name="q">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
```

i want to use the input i get from this input element and use it as variable in jquery . how can i do it?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do... You can always target your input with jquery selector `$('#search input')`.

Comment: I don't understand why you're using `getElementById` along with jQuery

Comment: even just `$('#q')` would give you the same element

Comment: @AdityaParab where does OP say they're using `getElementById` (*get*)?  Not really sure what OP means by *use the input I get from this input*

Comment: i dont know proper terminology. I will rewrite my question. Whatever the text I get from user i want to use it. how should i do that by id of element ("#element_name") ? in jquery?

Comment: ("#") selector will only give me that element right? not the value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the value of the input element by calling `.val()`.
See [jQuery docs for `val()`](https://api.jquery.com/val/)

In your code this could be

```js
var value = $("#q").val();
```